# Leaving and returning to Sweden while awaiting residence card

Tags: sweden, residency, spouses

Am I allowed to travel while I am in the process of getting a residence card (husband is an EU citizen, kids and I are not)? We got conflicting information from Migrationsverket: "you can," "no, you should stay and wait here." I have documents that show it is in process. Does anyone have his own experience?

Comment: Where do you want to travel to?

Comment: What's your nationality and where are you about to travel?

Comment: While waiting, do you have a temporary residence permit that is still valid? Would you be travelling with your EU-citizen husband?

Comment: @Dorothy her residence permit has already expired and she is waiting for an extension. Swedish migration agency does not issue temporary residence permits in such a cases.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk TY; and wouldn't that pose difficulties, not when leaving, but on the return?

Comment: @Dorothy unfortunately, that would; lots of people in Sweden struggle with this issue: majority decide to stay in Sweden while the Migration Agency is reviewing their extension application to avoid having difficulties re-entering Sweden.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk would you feel comfortable making that an answer? I'll upvote.

Comment: The thing is that very much depends on one's nationality and how long has the person been waiting for an extension. That's why OP has already received such a contradictory answers from the Migration Agency.